# $Emit is passing "undefined" property instead of an int property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently working on a VueJS application that fetches data from the API, views it on a table and the user would be able to perform certain functions on the array of objects. Now my issue is with the deletion of a row in the array. Below is the code of the button that emits a 'del-data' string alongside the ID of the row:

```
  <template #cell(actions)>
    <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" @click="$emit('del-data', items.id)" class="mr-1">
     Delete
    </b-button>
  </template>
```

This is then passed to the parent "App" component that is supposed to call the function when this occurs:

```
  <b-container id="app">
        <Navbar/>
        <router-view v-bind:items="items" v-on:del-data="deleteData" />
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios'
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios,axios)

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  data() {
    return {
        name: "app",
        items: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
      deleteData(id) {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8009/modservice/testdata/${id}`)
        .then(res => this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.id !== id, res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
  },
```

But the rows wouldn't delete in the table. I assume it is because instead of the child component emitting the ID property to the parent component so that it performs the "deleteData" function, it sends an undefined parameter as seen on the Vue events listener:

```
name:"del-data"
type:"$emit"
source:"<content>"
payload:Array[1]
0:undefined
```

I would appreciate any help on the matter as its been a complete nightmare trying to debug it for the past couple of days. If that is not the reason why it is not working and anyone might have an idea what is causing this, I would appreciate it.

Here is an image of the API I am fetching the data from if it helps:
[Image of API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaFJm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like `items` is an array

```
this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.id !== id, res.data))
```

so you either need to do

```
@click="$emit('del-data', items[0].id)"
```

or

```
this.items = this.items.find(item => item.id === id, res.data))
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, for the first suggestion the console shows that the emit returns a value but it is not equal to the ID in the array (and in consequence, no data is deleted in the local array). For the second one, it deletes the whole array when I attempt to delete one data row, do you have an idea why that might be the case?